# Mixin Type pattern not working

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a typing for AWS's Step Function configuration and the various "states" that a function can be made up consist of: {

```
export type StepFunctionState = IStepFunctionTask 
    & IStepFunctionChoice 
    & IStepFunctionWait;
```

I'm using the "mixin" pattern so that states can be any combination of different types of state. The various state definitions are:

```
export interface IStepFunctionTask extends IStepFunctionBaseState {
  Type: "Task";
  /** of the format arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-FUNCTION_NAME */
  Resource: AwsFunctionArn;
  Next?: string;
  End?: true;
  Retry?: [
    {
      ErrorEquals: string[];
      IntervalSeconds: number;
      BackoffRate: number;
      MaxAttemps: number;
    }
  ];
  Catch?: [
    {
      ErrorEquals: string[];
      Next: string;
    }
  ];
}

export interface IStepFunctionChoice extends IStepFunctionBaseState {
  Type: "Choice";
  Choices: [
    {
      /** points to the specific area of context which is being evaluated in the choice */
      Variable: string;
      /** compare the value passed in -- and scoped by "Variable" -- to be numerically equal to a stated number */
      NumericEquals?: number;
      /** the next state to move to when completed with this one */
      Next?: string;
      /** the step-function should stop at this step */
      End?: boolean;
    }
  ];
}

export interface IStepFunctionWait extends IStepFunctionBaseState {
  Type: "Wait";
  Seconds: number;
  Next: AwsFunctionArn;
}
```

where `IStepFunctionBaseState` just reinforces the required `Type` property which is the key part of the *discriminated union*:

```
export interface IDictionary<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
export type IStepFunctionType = "Task" | "Wait" | "Choice";
export interface IStepFunctionBaseState {
  Type: IStepFunctionType;
}
```

I can then assign reasonable data structures for each of these Task types:

```
const wait: IDictionary<IStepFunctionWait> = {
  yyy: {
    Type: "Wait",
    Seconds: 12,
    Next: "foo"
  }
};

const task: IDictionary<IStepFunctionTask> = {
  xxx: {
    Type: "Task",
    Resource: "arn",
    Next: "x2"
  },
  x2: {
    Type: "Task",
    Resource: "arn2",
    End: true
  }
};

const pass: IDictionary<IStepFunctionPass> = {
  pass: {
    Type: "Pass",
    Result: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2
    },
    ResultPath: "$.info",
    Next: "baz"
  }
};

const choice: IDictionary<IStepFunctionChoice> = {
  zzz: {
    Type: "Choice",
    Choices: [
      {
        Variable: "$.bar",
        NumericEquals: 1,
        Next: "xxx"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This all works but then what DOES NOT work is the following:

```
const mixedBag: IDictionary<StepFunctionState> = {
  ...task,
  ...choice,
  ...wait
};
```

I get a number of errors on the definition of `mixedBag` where it complains:

> Type '{ Type: "Task"; Resource: string; Next?: string; End?: true; Retry?: [{ ErrorEquals: string[]; In...' is not assignable to type '{ Type: "Task"; Resource: string; Next?: string; End?: true; Retry?: [{ ErrorEquals: string[]; In...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

as well as

> Property 'Resource' is missing in type '{ Type: "Choice"; Choices: [{ Variable: string; NumericEquals?: number; Next?: string; End?: bool...'.

[image]

Hopefully this is enough context for folks to help but let me know if you need more.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `IStepFunctionChoice` and `IStepFunctionWait`? Replacing that picture with actual code would also help.

Comment: I'll add that now but I'm quite sure that it's not a problem in that area.

Comment: Could you also add the code not the a picture of your initialization code, makes it easier to copy paste and test :)

Comment: I have updated to have code instead of image; I had originally posted the image to illustrate the lack of errors but I can see that text is more useful for folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [intersection types (`&`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) are used when you want the object to have all the properties in the union (so all steps would have all the properties of `IStepFunctionTask` and `IStepFunctionChoice` and `IStepFunctionWait` all at the same time). Obviously a task will be either a `IStepFunctionWait` or `IStepFunctionChoice` or `IStepFunctionTask`, which can be modeled using union types (`|`)

```
export type StepFunctionState = IStepFunctionTask 
    | IStepFunctionChoice 
    | IStepFunctionWait;

const mixedBag: IDictionary<StepFunctionState> = {
    ...task,
    ...choice,
    ...wait
};
```

Comment: Let me try that again ... I had alternated between the two but my understanding was that the `&` operator was correct if the Dictionary was able to have properties which had a mix of Task, Choice, and Wait states whereas you'd use the `|` operator when the dictionary had either Tasks, Choices, etc. but not a mixture.

Comment: Well i am happy to stand corrected ... this does work with the `|` operator. Thanks for the nudge.